# jQuery error = SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery

There seems to be a lot of these errors on SO but I can't find any to relate to.

The error is: `SyntaxError: missing : after property id` and it's complaining about this line: `var msg = "";` (Line 3).

```
function checkSubmission()({

    var msg = "";

    $('#validation').html(msg);

    if ($("#lms_name").val().length<=0){    
        msg+="LMS Name Required.<br/>";
    }else{

        var value = $('#lms_name').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,}$/);
        if(value.match(regex)) {

        } else {
             msg+="<b>Error on LMS name : </b>Numbers and letters only. Minimum of two characters.<br/>";
        }
    }

    //lots more code here...
```

Any ideas? FYI I'm a complete newbie (for now...).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code in this question has absolutely nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Fixing tags now.

Comment: You have an extra opening parenthesis in here:  `checkSubmission()({` should be `checkSubmission() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your comment on @Shoaib Raza, prompted me to post this. (*please accept his answer rather than mine, since his was first.*)

---

**Quote OP Comment:**

> FYI, I changed it to just `function checkSubmission( var msg = "";` ... and the error still appeared.

And that's totally wrong too. `checkSubmission( ...` is not what his answer is showing, so the new error message is accurate:  `SyntaxError: missing ( before { -> function checkSubmission{`

---

This line of your original code contains the original syntax error...

```
function checkSubmission()({
```

**should be this...**

```
function checkSubmission() {
```

Notice the difference?  You simply need to remove the extra `(` and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky, I clearly lost the plot when creating this post and exploring the answers and for that I apologise greatly. I have the code working now.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to :

```
    function checkSubmission()
    {

        var msg = "";

        $('#validation').html(msg);

        if ($("#lms_name").val().length<=0)
        {    
            msg+="LMS Name Required.<br/>";
        }
        else
        {

            var value = $('#lms_name').val();
            var regex = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,}$/);
            if(value.match(regex)) 
            {

            } 
            else 
            {
                 msg+="<b>Error on LMS name : </b>Numbers and letters only. Minimum of two characters.<br/>";
            }
        }
//lot more code in the function here.. if any
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To be honest, I think I'm blending Javascript and JQuery... to the JQuery Validation docs! xD

Comment: FYI, I changed it to just function `checkSubmission( var msg = "";` ... and the error still appeared.

Comment: Write your function as : function checkSubmission() { //your full code }

Comment: Error has changed to `SyntaxError: missing ( before {` -> `function checkSubmission{`

Comment: Create fiddle or post your full code ..

Comment: jQuery Validation docs?  What are you talking about? ... there is no code in your question that has anything to do with the jQuery Validation plugin.  What does "blending" jQuery and JavaScript mean?  jQuery **IS** JavaScript.

Comment: @Arbiter, the code in your comments indicates that you're not paying attention to what this answer or the error message is telling you to do:  **`function checkSubmission() {`**